# Typescript Class Initializing Static Variable

Tags: typescript

This is a general best practices question. I have a TS class something like the following.

```
class Foo {
    
    private static bar: string;


    static fooBar(value: string): string {
        this.bar = value;
        return `foo ${this.bar}`;
    }
}
```

My question is, is it bad practice to initialize `bar` inside the method? I was told that doing so mutates the object and "mutations should be avoid when possible". The way this class would be used would like the following.

```
const foobar = Foo.fooBar('bar');
```

I don't think in the instance the object is being mutated, but I am not a TS expert. Some insight would be very much helpful. Is this a bad implementation? If so, what would be best practice in this example.

Thank you!

UPDATE:

So I'm using this pattern to create "Service" class to house methods the http request. ex.

```
export abstract class HttpService {

    /**
     * Checks Response status before returning
     * the payload. If the status is not OK, then
     * throws an Error including the response status
     *
     * @param response Response from request
     */
    static onResponse(response: Response): never | Promise<any> {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error(`HTTP::Response An error has occurred -> response ${response}}`);
        }
    }
}
```

```
export class BooksService extends HttpService {

    private static uri: string;

    public static async getBooks(): Promise<any> {
        this.uri = config.api.booksUri;

        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                ...headers.headers,
            }
        };

        return await fetch(this.uri, options).then(this.onResponse);
    }
}
```

My thought process behind the `private static url` was just minimize the code a bit and not declare `const url` variable in every method.

Comment: *"The way this class would be used would like the following"* That would throw an error, `Foo.bar` is not a function. Did you mean `Foo.fooBar("bar")`? (Note: Meaningful names are clearer than nonsense.)

Comment: Mutation itself isn't inherently bad (your state needs to be updated _somewhere_), but ambiguous or confusing state is. Until you call `Foo.fooBar`, `Foo.bar` is uninitialized. And invoking `Foo.fooBar` has side effects that alter the state which aren't obvious from the contract. Global mutable variables have no lifetime constraints and can be shared so it's hard to narrow down where a value came from. All these things aren't horrible by themselves, but the more you follow good practices, the more likely it is that your code is easier to follow/debug and less prone to bugs.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I meant ```Foo.fooBar("bar")``` and was suppose to be private. I've made some updates the post. I'll add my "real world" usage of this pattern. Thank you all for the input!!

Comment: I assume ```return `foo ${bar}`;``` **also** has the `this.` you added in the edit? E.g., it's really ```return `foo ${this.bar}`;```?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes that's correct, I updated the post above.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think in the instance the object is being mutated...

`Foo`, the function object with a `bar` property, is indeed mutated by that code, because in a `static` function on `Foo` called as `Foo.fooBar("bar")`, `this` refers to the `Foo` function, so the method assigns to the `bar` property, which is a `static` property (a property of the `Foo` function itself). Every time `fooBar` is called, `bar` would get reassigned.

```js
class Foo {
    
    /*private*/ static bar/*: string*/;

    static fooBar(value/*: string*/)/*: string*/ {
        this.bar = value;
        return `foo ${this.bar}`;
    }
}

Foo.fooBar("1");
console.log(`Foo.bar = ${Foo.bar}`); // "Foo.bar = 1"

Foo.fooBar("2");
console.log(`Foo.bar = ${Foo.bar}`); // "Foo.bar = 2"
```

Whether mutating objects is bad depends on what style of programming you're using. In some styles it's absolutely fine and normal, in other styles (such as functional programming) it's strongly discouraged). In your original question `bar` was public, and modifying a public static property of a constructor function is almost universally discouraged. In an edit you've changed it to `private` which takes us more in the realm of opinion/style. (I feel like I should follow that up with an opinion on doing it, but opinions is off-topic for SO questions and answers.)

Comment: Could explain why the access change to private changes the question to be more opinionated/styling question? I am very much aware of SOs views on opinionated questions/answers from experience lol. I have identical code up for a PR and this pattern doesn't present any bad practices or mutation issue, then I don't mind taking down this question. I would love to know what your thoughts to the pattern.

Comment: @JosephFreeman - That's just my own, possibly-flawed, view. But having a publicly-accessible property on a constructor function whose value depends on the last call made to a method on that constructor function just seems like an especially bad idea, even in mutation-is-find circles. Constructor functions being that dynamic just feels wrong. But with it being private, it becomes an implementation detail of the class, something internal, which seems much more okay.

Comment: @JosephFreeman - Here's an example: You know that on browsers, `setTimeout` returns a number that uniquely identifies the timer you just set. Naturally, that number is stored somewhere in the implementation, privately. Now suppose it was a public property of the `setTimeout` function. Then any code could find out the handle of the most-recently started timer. That's not a good idea. :-)